# USB Flash drives up to 2TB?

Tags: usb, memory, flash, computers

I found USB Flash drives on aliexpress.com up to 2 TB. So much people bought them, and I'm reading feedbacks and 90% says: "It works perfectly, thanks", just a few customers have left a negative feedbacks. Is it possible that flash drive with 2 TB of memory space exists nowadays? Why not, and whats the maximum flash drive storage capacity? Which type of formatting do they use, FAT32, NTFS? What is this all about?

[Here is the link](http://www.aliexpress.com/af/flash-1-tb.html?ltype=wholesale&SearchText=flash%201%20tb&isOnlyAffiliate=y&d=y&origin=n&initiative_id=AS_20150430013411&isViewCP=y&catId=711005)

Comment: I have to say, this got me very interested. However, it's very likely a scam.

Comment: But I saw they sell that drives and getting feedbacks from 500 customers, all positive, just a few have left negative.

Comment: I just want to know, why it's not possible nowadays?

Comment: @Lazar It's possible, but that says nothing about whether what you buy actually has that storage capacity. Many of us could design one for you, but that still doesn't say whether someone has designed it and is manufacturing it and selling it on aliexpress. It's often trivial to take a, say, 32GB memory stick and make it "appear" to be 2TB. It'll "work" until it fills up and then you're done for.

Answer (score 6):

Usually the size is a few GB, with a custom firmware that gives you the illusion that you have 2TB, but when you start filling it up it starts deleting old files, see here: http://www.instructables.com/id/Dont-fall-for-the-Flash-Drive-Scam!/

Comment: They are very wise, many people fall for that. So why it's not possible to have that large capacity flash drives?

Comment: @Lazar Let me paraphrase, _"They are very offensive, many people suffer from that."_

Comment: Hundreds of thousands of people have make the same mistake you did on eBay. We did. You are not alone. The scam is now over 10 years old. - Source sosfakeflash.wordpress.com

Comment: @Lazar "why it's not possible to have that large capacity flash drives" It's possible. Just because it's possible, doesn't mean that it's a product. It's possible to use Siri voice input in a nuclear missile bunker, but that doesn't mean that it's a good idea, or that anyone makes such hardware.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that there's actually a 2 TB Flash Drive yet, at least not one that actually is 2 TB.  However, Kingston has made a  [1 TB flash drive](http://www.kingston.com/us/company/press/article/6487) and you can buy it for about [$800 on Newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=0BD-0003-000E1). Still though, I'm not sure that having a flash drive that big that would be the best idea just yet; I'm sure they have many bugs to still work out.  You wouldn't want to store a TB of data on a flash drive just to plug it in the next day and find out that it's not working any more.

Answer (score 1):

> Why it's not possible to have that large capacity flash drives?

Simply speaking, the technology is not there, quite yet. At least not in the $10 market sector.

For example, Samsung is one of the leaders in R&D of multi-layer NAND Flash memory. [link](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/html/product/flash-solution/vnand/overview.html), [reference](http://thememoryguy.com/tag/3d-nand/); And yet, they "only" produce a 1TB 2.5'' SSD.

I have no doubt however, that we will see proper terabyte-range pen drives in the future. Just not on Ebay for $18.